# FileStream Access Denied in ASP hosted web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, file

I have the following

```
//get the data as a string.
 using (FileStream fs = File.Open(location, FileMode.Open))
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
 {
     rawData = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

in the web config of the WCF host

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate ="true"/>
```

however i get this error

Access to the path 'D:\some dir\rules.txt'

The host in hosted in IIS 6, using a VirDir, with annon access account as me, and the rules.txt has full access from me.

what im i missing. i have also given "everyone" access, yet no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved,

gave access to the Network Service account